Finding the probability $P(X_1 \le y_1, X_1 + X_2 \le y_2)$.
I am working on the following problem.

Suppose $\{X_1, X_2\} \sim  \exp(\lambda)$. Find
$$P(X_1\le y_1, X_1 +
X_2 \le y_2),$$ where $0 < y_1 < y_2$.

I have done the following.
\begin{align}
P(X_1\le y_1, X_1 + X_2 \le y_2) &= P(X_1 \le y_1) \cdot  P(X_2 \le y_2 - X_1) \\
 &= \int_{y_1}^{0} \lambda e^{-\lambda X_1}\, \mathrm{d}X_1 \cdot \int_{0}^{y_2-X_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda X_2}\, \mathrm{d}X_2 .
\end{align}
I computed the integral, but I compared my answer to other sources, and it seems I made a mistake in choosing my bound for the integral over $X_2$. Which boundaries should I select when solving the problem this way and why?

If the integral  you computed is $\lambda  y_1 \left(-e^{\lambda  (-y_2)}\right)-e^{\lambda  (-y_1)}+1$, then you probably chose the correct bounds.

Although $X_1, X_2$ are presume to be independent, you cannot turn the joint probability into product like that in general as both involving $X_1$. Instead maybe you try to conditional on $X_1$, applying the law of total probability.

be more clear about your assumptions

Your $$\left(\int_{x_1=y_1}^{0} \lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}\, \mathrm{d}x_1\right) \cdot \left(\int_{x_2=0}^{y_2-x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}\, \mathrm{d}x_2\right)$$ has a couple of issues:
(a) the right hand integral will leave a free $x_1$ in the result, but the answer should only contain $y_1$ and $y_2$;  this is equivalent to saying that $X_1$ and $X_2$ being unconditionally independent does not mean that the events $0 < X_2 \le y_2-X_1$ and $0 < X_1 \le y_1$ are independent;
(b) the limits on the left hand integral have been reversed.
Correcting these would give
$$\int_{x_1=0}^{y_1} \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1} \cdot \int_{x_2=0}^{y_2-x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}\, \mathrm{d}x_2\right) \, \mathrm{d}x_1 = \int_{x_1=0}^{y_1}\int_{x_2=0}^{y_2-x_1} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda (x_1+x_2)}\, \mathrm{d}x_2 \, \mathrm{d}x_1$$
and the answer in JimB's comment to the original question.
